# Why can't i access a variable inside my while loop

Tags: java, netbeans

For some reason i cant access a variable from inside my while loop. I've checked other posts on this however i still cant seem to figure it out.

hears my code:

```
package pandacare;
import java.util.Random;
public class PandaCare {

Random r = new Random();

int HWT;

int hunger = 0;
int fun = 0;
int thirst = 0;
int energy = 0;
int hygiene = 0;
int points = 0;
int coins = 1000;
int total = hunger + fun +thirst + energy + hygiene;

public void hungerWait(){
    int Low = 5;
    int High = 30;
    HWT = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    hunger --;
}

    while(hunger > 0){
       hungerWait();
    }

}
```

Comment: Because the while-loop is outside of any method...

Comment: MadProgrammer is right, where is your main method by the way, and which variable you cannot access?

Comment: if i put it in the main method i said i can access non-static variable and non-static function

Comment: my main method is in the Jframe class

Comment: @DaneAshman it is not clear where your issue is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a moment and look at your code closely...

```
public class PandaCare {

    //...

    public void hungerWait() {
        int Low = 5;
        int High = 30;
        HWT = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        hunger--;
    }

    // This won't work, it's not a valid statement...
    while(hunger > 0){
       hungerWait();
    }

}
```

The `while(hunger > 0)` is outside of any method.  Code can only be executed within static blocks/initialises or methods...

You need to wrap the loop inside some kind of method...

For (a crude) example...

```
public class PandaCare {

    //...

    public void hungerWait() {
        int Low = 5;
        int High = 30;
        HWT = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        hunger--;
    }

    public void waitTillNoHungry() {        
        while(hunger > 0){
           hungerWait();
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: if i put the while loop in a method will it still always check if the thing in between the brackets is true? @MadProgrammer

Comment: It's a method, if you call it, it will run the code...

Comment: is there a way to make the method always run? @MadProgrammer

Comment: but it cant call a non static method in the main method @MadProgrammer

Comment: im sorry, im a bit of a noob

Comment: Make an instance of `PandaCare` and call it's method.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! @ MadProgrammer